# Invalid JSON response from RIPE database

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

RIPE is providing an API, which allows to query their database with a simple GET query with json response.

I am not sure how fast their release cycle is, and when they will fix this. Thus need to find an workaround how to use their API. Can anybody suggest a hack how to address this JSON issue?

[You can see the result here](http://rest.db.ripe.net/search.json?query-string=8.8.8.8)
The JSON response is syntactically correct, just badly declared causing the "object" to override its previous declaration.

To illustrate the problem, this is their simplified response.

```
{
"objects" : {
    "object" : [{"type" : "inetnum"}],
    "object" : [{"type" : "person"}],
    "object" : [{"type" : "route"]}
}
```

}

which is after evaluation identical to this

```
{
    "objects" : {
        "object" : [{"type" : "route"]}
    }
}
```

All processing needs to happen in a browser so JavaScript only. Is there any option how to get access to the other "object" values?

This is how I am querying the API

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://rest.db.ripe.net/search.json",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        "query-string": "8.8.8.8",
        format: "json"
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```

*In case anybody else depends on the RIPE API, here is a link to the [bug](https://github.com/RIPE-NCC/whois/issues/114)*

Comment: I cannot think of any. Since your making a JSONP call, the response is directly evaluated as JavaScript, before you can do anything. So at that moment, the object literal has already been interpreted. But the result you linked to only shows one `object:` entry, so are you sure that this is actually a problem? This would be a huge bug actually. [According to their documentation](https://github.com/RIPE-NCC/whois/wiki/WHOIS-REST-API-search), `objects.object` should be an array.

Comment: For the IP address 8.8.8.8 there are two `object`s one with type `inetnum` and the other with type `route`. I guess the response should be the same for whoever is asking. Did you try to use a different IP address?

Comment: Oh wow, you are right. I copied the response to http://jsonlint.org to format it properly, but it silently removes the duplicate entries. So you are right, the response is definitely not useful in this format. But as I said, there is nothing you can do from your end, at least from the client side. You could create your own sever side script, get the response as JSON (not JSONP) and do some string processing. Are they aware of this bug? If not, you should file a bug report.

Comment: Exactly, it took me a while to realize what is the issue as well. It can't be easily spotted as the json is syntactically correct. Yes, I did file the bug.